# Java Regular Expression not working (but does at Rubular)

Tags: regex

at [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) i was testing my Regular expression:

```
(\d+).html
```

Test string:

```
"/magnoliaAuthor/Services/services/07.html"
```

Just as I needed, I returned "07" as the first match group. Perfect.
I need this regex in an Java environment, so I wrote this piece of code:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Main
{
  public static void main (String[] args) 
  {
    String jcrPath = "/magnoliaAuthor/Services/services/07.html";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+).html");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(jcrPath);
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
  }
}
```

As explained [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#regex_backslashes), I added anothere \ to my regex.
Sadly for me, when compiling and running the code, I get the following exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found

Does anybody know why there aren't any matches?

Comment: The dot is a special character, too. Try `"(\\d+)\\.html"`. Also, you are matching the regex on the entire string, so it should be `".*(\\d+)\\.html"` where the `.+` at the beginning is an arbitrary sequence of characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *apply* the pattern, too:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\.html"); // compiles the regex
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(jcrPath);         // creates a Matcher object 
if (matcher.find()) {                               // performs the actual match
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: Reason: matcher.matches() would yield false as matches requires full matching.

Comment: @JoopEggen: He isn't calling `matcher.matches()`, either :)

Comment: I meant that `group` has no meaning without preceding `find` or `matches`.

Comment: As per requirement, you will need to change group() to group(1) if you only want 07 returned.  This answer will return 07.html

Answer (score 2):

The javadoc for `Matcher#group()` says:

> Returns the input subsequence matched by the previous match.

That means you'll have to execute a `matcher.matches()` or `matcher.find()` before using the `group()` method. In your case `matcher.find()`will be the correct one, since `matcher.matches()` checks if the *entire* input string is matched by the pattern.